# onClick is not reacting in quiz

Tags: javascript, onclick

I'm doing this project for school with a quiz in JavaScript. After clicking the button I want it to show a message but for some reason after clicking nothing happens. Could you guys help me? I went through it few times and still don't know what's wrong;/

```js
function check() {
  var question1 = document.quiz.question1.value;
  var question2 = document.quiz.question2.value;
  var question3 = document.quiz.question3.value;
  var question4 = document.quiz.question4.value;
  var question5 = document.quiz.question5.value;
  var question6 = document.quiz.question6.value;
  var question7 = document.quiz.question7.value;
  var question8 = document.quiz.question8.value;
  var correct = 0;
  if (question1 == "voldoende" || "goed") {
    correct++;
  }
  if (question2 == "Voldoende" || "Goed") {
    correct++;
  }
  if (question3 == "Voldoende" || "Goed") {
    correct++;
  }
  if (question4 == "Voldoende" || "Goed") {
    correct++;
  }
  if (question5 == "Voldoende" || "Goed") {
    correct++;
  }
  if (question6 == "Voldoende" || "Goed") {
    correct++;
  }
  if (question7 == "Voldoende" || "Goed") {
    correct++;
  }
  if (question8 == "Voldoende" || "Goed") {
    correct++;
  }
  var messages = ["You passed!", "You failed", "You did awesome"];
  var range;
  if (correct < 5) {
    range = 1;
  }
  if (correct > 5 && correct < 8) {
    range = 0;
  }
  if (correct == 8) {
    range = 2;
  }
  document.getElementById("after_submit").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = messages[range];
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

after_submit {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheets.css"> </head>

<body>
  <h1>Will I get a good grade for this project?</h1>
  <form id="quiz" name="quiz">
    <p>Is my code interactief?</p>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question1" value="genant">Genant
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question1" value="voldoende">Voldoende
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question1" value="goed">Goed
    <br>
    <p>Dom Manipulatie</p>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question2" value="genant">Genant
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question2" value="voldoende">Voldoende
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question2" value="goed">Goed
    <br>
    <p>Controle Structuren</p>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question3" value="genant">Genant
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question3" value="voldoende">Voldoende
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question3" value="goed">Goed
    <br>
    <p>Loops</p>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question4" value="genant">Genant
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question4" value="voldoende">Voldoende
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question4" value="goed">Goed
    <br>
    <p>Array/object</p>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question5" value="genant">Genant
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question5" value="voldoende">Voldoende
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question5" value="goed">Goed
    <br>
    <p>Functies</p>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question6" value="genant">Genant
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question6" value="voldoende">Voldoende
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question6" value="goed">Goed
    <br>
    <p>Flow</p>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question7" value="genant">Genant
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question7" value="voldoende">Voldoende
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question7" value="goed">Goed
    <br>
    <p>Kwaliteit</p>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question8" value="genant">Genant
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question8" value="voldoende">Voldoende
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question8" value="goed">Goed
    <br>
    <input id="button" type="button" value="Check my grade" onclick="check();"> </form>
  <div id="after_submit">
    <p id="message"></p>
    <p id="number_correct"></p>
  </div>
  <script src="js/game.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Any way someone could explain why do I always get the same answer?? I really suck at this;/

Answer (score 2):

You need to change all your `question1.value` `question2.value`... to `Question1.value` `Question2.value` ... since that's the name of your inputs

But you still need to check your logic because no matter which choice you select on your radio buttons, you always get the message "You did awesome"

Comment: Why is that? If less than 5 answers are incorrect then it should give the message "you failed", right?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4qb877jc/ check it on jsfiddle, I even let all the buttons unselected and it told me "You did awesome" you are getting the values of your buttons, but not the value of the selected ones, you need to read more into radio button selected options

Comment: Thats weird. I saw online the same code just with different values and it worked just fine;/ Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

Press **F12** to see **Developer tools**. In the Console, you'll see  error messages like this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined
```

That means that `document.quiz.question1`, ... are not defined. Why? Because properties names are wrong. Write (note the uppercase character):

```
document.quiz.Question1
```

Answer (score 0):

> I've spotted MANY ERRORS in your code (Either programmaticly or
>   logically) 
> 1. *Goed* is not the same with *goed*, so as
>   *Voldoende* and *voldoende* (Consider **consistency of case** whether it's HTML or Javascript. Yes, **HTML is not a Case-sensitive language
>   but Javascript do**. 
>  2. **5 points shows undefined** -> must use
>   `correct <= 5` condition 
>  3. **Logical Operation Related Concern**
>   -> `question1 == "voldoende"` is not the same as `"voldoende"` (Solution: still rewrite `question1 == value` on the right side of or
>   operator) -> **this is also the main reason why you always get 8 points.  (Right side of the or operator is ALWAYS TRUE, you're just restating that `"goed" == "goed"` if you don't include the `questionN ==` code)**
>
> Lastly @Jérémie L's statement, **F12 Developer tools** which he have
>   used, is basically the thing to use to address such problems :) It
>   helps alot. **Use breakpoints to know the value of each line / blocks
>   of codes.**

Snippet below contains correct script of your project.

I've put comment tags on the changes for readability

```js
function check() {
<!-- question1 to Question1, right side of assignment operator -> due to case sensitivity, must be first letters capitalized in both JS and HTML -->
  var question1 = document.quiz.Question1.value;
  var question2 = document.quiz.Question2.value;
  var question3 = document.quiz.Question3.value;
  var question4 = document.quiz.Question4.value;
  var question5 = document.quiz.Question5.value;
  var question6 = document.quiz.Question6.value;
  var question7 = document.quiz.Question7.value;
  var question8 = document.quiz.Question8.value;
  var correct = 0;
  <!-- goed on the right side of logical operator must contain question1 == on its left, always remember -->
  if (question1 == "voldoende" || question1 == "goed") {
    correct++;
  }
  if (question2 == "voldoende" || question2 == "goed") {
    correct++;
  }
  if (question3 == "voldoende" || question3 == "goed") {
    correct++;
  }
  if (question4 == "voldoende" || question4 == "goed") {
    correct++;
  }
  if (question5 == "voldoende" || question5 == "goed") {
    correct++;
  }
  if (question6 == "voldoende" || question6 == "goed") {
    correct++;
  }
  if (question7 == "voldoende" || question7 == "goed") {
    correct++;
  }
  if (question8 == "voldoende" || question8 == "goed") {
    correct++;
  }
  var messages = ["You passed!", "You failed", "You did awesome"];
  var range;
  <!-- correct < 5 to correct <= 5, making no space for undefined message -->
  if (correct <= 5) {
    range = 1;
  }
  if (correct > 5 && correct < 8) {
    range = 0;
  }
  if (correct == 8) {
    range = 2;
  }
  document.getElementById("after_submit").style.visibility = "visible";
  document.getElementById("message").innerHTML = messages[range];
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

after_submit {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheets.css"> </head>

<body>
  <h1>Will I get a good grade for this project?</h1>
  <form id="quiz" name="quiz">
    <p>Is my code interactief?</p>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question1" value="genant">Genant
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question1" value="voldoende">Voldoende
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question1" value="goed">Goed
    <br>
    <p>Dom Manipulatie</p>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question2" value="genant">Genant
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question2" value="voldoende">Voldoende
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question2" value="goed">Goed
    <br>
    <p>Controle Structuren</p>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question3" value="genant">Genant
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question3" value="voldoende">Voldoende
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question3" value="goed">Goed
    <br>
    <p>Loops</p>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question4" value="genant">Genant
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question4" value="voldoende">Voldoende
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question4" value="goed">Goed
    <br>
    <p>Array/object</p>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question5" value="genant">Genant
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question5" value="voldoende">Voldoende
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question5" value="goed">Goed
    <br>
    <p>Functies</p>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question6" value="genant">Genant
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question6" value="voldoende">Voldoende
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question6" value="goed">Goed
    <br>
    <p>Flow</p>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question7" value="genant">Genant
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question7" value="voldoende">Voldoende
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question7" value="goed">Goed
    <br>
    <p>Kwaliteit</p>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question8" value="genant">Genant
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question8" value="voldoende">Voldoende
    <br>
    <input id="mc" type="radio" name="Question8" value="goed">Goed
    <br>
    <input id="button" type="button" value="Check my grade" onclick="check();"> </form>
  <div id="after_submit">
    <p id="message"></p>
    <p id="number_correct"></p>
  </div>
  <script src="js/game.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```